# how to split 2 or more groups to have on average the same value on each of 2 or more attributes

Tags: statistics, optimization

Say you have a set $\omega$ containing $n$ elements. Each element of this set has 5 attributes $\{x\in\omega|x\in\mathbb{N}^5\}$, where each attribute can have integer values between 0 and 9 . How do you split the set in half in a way that the first subset of elements $\psi_1$ has on average the same value on every attribute as the second subset ? i.e. $\psi_2 \approx \psi_1$ at every category

Also, what if you wanted to split the set in different ratio than $1:1$ ? or if you wanted more than 2 subsets ?

**Note** as mentioned by @Watercrystal this is the optimization version of the partition problem which is NP-hard. So as indicated in Wikipedia this is the description:

> partition the multiset $S$ into two subsets $S_1$, $S_2$ such that the
> difference between the sum of elements in S1 and the sum of elements
> in S2 is minimized

Any solution or lead on this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard, so no (exact) polynomial time algorithm is known. However, there are pseudo-polynomial algorithms for it.

Comment: thanks for the indicator. Any solution you know to this ? or something I can look into ?

Comment: The wikipedia page I linked has some starting points.